# My code doesn't return the right value of a cookie generate with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, events, cookies

I'm trying to set two different types of users, visitor or exhibitor on a wordpress website. To do that, i have two links on the top of my header.php.

```
<a href="" id="">visitor</a>
<a href="" id="">exhibitor</a>
```

Using jquery.cookie.js, I set a cookie called user_type in my js file main.js.

```
$('a#btn-visiteur').click(function(){
    $.cookie('user_type', 'visitor', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
});
$('a#btn-exposant').click(function(){
    $.cookie('user_type', 'exhibitor', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
});
```

Back in my header.php, I just want to show that my cookie is set correctly so i just echo the cookies in my file.

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['user_type'])){

        if($_COOKIE['user_type'] == 'visitor'){
            echo 'visitor';
        }
        if($_COOKIE['user_type'] == 'exhibitor'){
            echo 'exhibitor';
        }

} ?>
```

Using Firebug, i see that my cookie is correctly set but my php code doesn't return the  right result. It just show the previous value of the cookie.

I hope that its understandable i'm not very comfortable with english. Dear people of stackoverflow, I need your help.

Thank by advance.

Comment: Are you setting the cookie with javascript and then later down the page checking the value with php? If so, PHP isnt going to know about the value until you reload the page. If you can, set the cookie with PHP. As it stands, any user can change themselves to an exhibitor using javascript.

Comment: Cookies are saved on the computer of the vistor. This means that the vistor can manipulate the data anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reload the page after you set the variables.

Example:

```
$('a#btn-visiteur').on('click',function(){
    $.cookie('user_type', 'visitor', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I already reload the pages using those links. Thanks for helping.